# Erro 503 no Wordpress / Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, woocommerce

Precisando de ajuda.

De repente a loja no woocommerce começa apresentar erros 503

```
    Service Unavailable 

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
```

olhando os logs de erro tenho:

```
[Thu Apr 20 20:01:12.818049 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7147:tid 139769711425280] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client xxxx] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling), referer: xxxx/finalizar-compra/
```

[Thu Apr 20 20:12:09.925804 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7147:tid 139769526785792] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client xxxx:xxx] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling), referer: xxxxx/wp-admin/post.php?post=3468&action=edit
[Thu Apr 20 20:12:17.381389 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7147:tid 139769593927424] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client xxxx] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling), referer: xxx/wp-admin/post.php?post=3468&action=edit

em varias partes, como finalizar compra, editar pedido e por ai vai.
não achei a causa do erro.

Já aumentei os timeout, uso de memória e mesmo assim não funcionou.

alguém sabe a causa e resolução?

Comment: outras páginas .php ocorrem o mesmo problema? Se ocorrer é porque o servidor esta em modo de manutenção provavelmente.

Comment: sim, mas o erro so acontece quando finaliza uma compra, muda o statu do pedido e outros processos